# c++ win32 textarea with line numbers?

Tags: c++, winapi, textarea, line-numbers

I'm writing a notepad program using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express with Win32. I have the basic design for it, however I would like to be able to show line numbers next to the textarea, like you see in most text editors (i.e notepad++, sublime, etc.). The code i have for the textarea is:

```
hEdit = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 0, 0, 100, 100, hwnd, ( HMENU )IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL );
            if( hEdit == NULL )
                MessageBox( hwnd, "Could not create edit box.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );

            hfDefault = CreateFont( 0, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, 0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, TEXT( "Consolas" ) );
            SendMessage( hEdit, WM_SETFONT, ( WPARAM )hfDefault, MAKELPARAM( FALSE, 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a standard `EDIT` multi-line control does not *natively* support the display of line numbers, this is fairly easy to accomplish manually with a little work.

You can use [`EM_SETRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761657.aspx)/[`EM_SETRECTNP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761659.aspx) to create space for a gutter along one side of the control, and then you can subclass the control to intercept its `WM_PAINT` messages so you can draw your own line numbers in the gutter as needed.

While drawing, you can use [`EM_CHARFROMPOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761566.aspx), [`EM_LINEFROMCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761609.aspx), and [`EM_POSFROMCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761631.aspx) to help you translate client-area coordinates into line numbers, and calculate line heights.

Answer (score 1):

The "EDIT" control does not have any built in support for line numbers (or anything else) in the margin. Create another "EDIT" control beside the first and put the line numbers in that one.